# Why people using variable functions for add_action or add_filter in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

**I just was wondering why people do something like :**

```
function world_func() {
   return 'world';
}
add_action('hello',world_func);
```

**Instead of :**

```
add_action('hello',function(){
   return 'world';
});
```

I see many functions are not re-useable (unique)

**Why? What's different? Performance? This is bad ?**

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240432/anonymous-functions-in-wordpress-hooks One of the answers speaks about the importance of not using closures in plugins which might need the function to be over ridden